# load textbox value on angucomplete item selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to load value in textbox when angucomplete item selected.

This is how I declare the directive in my html file:

`<angucomplete id="autoName" placeholder="Name" pause="100" name="customer" selectedobject="sel" localdata="names" searchfields="custName" titlefield="custName" inputclass="form-control form-control-small" />`

and i want selected value in textbox declared as:

`<input id='autoValue' type="text" class="form-control" name='custValue' ng-model="selVal" minlength="15" placeholder="custmer value" required>`

i tried this one but on pageload getting initial value error

`<input id='autoValue' type="text" class="form-control" name='custValue' ng-model="selVal = sel.originalObject.value" minlength="15" placeholder="custmer value" required>`

using above solution after selecting item from angucomplete value updated in textbox but textbox become non-editable. **so is there any way to update value in textbox without making non-editable**

Comment: move this line to controller : selVal = sel.originalObject.value, because angucomplete is a directive, it's better if you post more informations on html and js code

Comment: but selVal is myController variable and sel.originalObject is angucomplete directive controller variable. I cant access  sel.originalObject in myController or selVal in directiveController.